# casting void* and put it in ostringstream

Tags: c++, casting, void-pointers

I have problem with `void *` I want to put what contain in a string to output it,I know that in compiling moment the compiler doesn't know what the pointer point to so I think to use a kind of cast(cast the `*(void*)` to string ) the static_cast:

```
  std::string get_Info_Field (std::string nameTab,int IDF)   

  {     ostringstream os;
        iter=Inst_Data.find(nameTab);

        if(iter!= Inst_Data.end())
        {   iterF=(iter->second).find(IDF);
            if(iterF!=(iter->second).end())
                    {os<<*static_cast<std::string*>(iterF->second.value);}
            else    { os<<""; }
        }
        else {  os<<"";}

    return os.str();
};
```

here `iterF->second.value` is a `void*` that I want to get its value that can point to any type(int,string,float,long,char..), my question is :is that safe? will return the right value of the pointer whatever the type ? I tested with `int` it works but I'am not sure for the rest.

please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There's probably a better way than using a void*, could this be turned into a template function which actually handles the correct types rather than using unsafe casts?

Comment: thanks Benj, template are safer for sure, but in my project I have a generic class named _Field_ and a derived class for each type of value(intField,stringField...),is still better to use a template and one class that handle all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't safely cast an pointer to an arbitrary value to a string and expect something sensible to happen; at absolute minimum you also need to know the size of the thing pointed to, and you may also need to watch out for embedded `NUL`s and the like.  If you *know* that it is always a `std::string` then you can cast to a `std::string` safely; but you do have to know with certainty, or you're courting a core dump or random output.

Comment: thanks for your time, in fact the type of value can be int,float,string ... is't always string, so for that I want to get this value and put it in a string that I can output it and use it (I need to compare it whit other Field value)

Comment: What I said is still true; at minimum you need a size (so you can treat it as an arbitrary base+length byte array), preferably you should use some typed representation (an object which knows how to copy itself, or the container should be a template type).

Comment: I can't use a template cause I have an object `Table` that have a map of `Field`s, here it can be any type of Field I don't know witch type to indicate for the template when declaring it.

Comment: Then you will need to use some other means of identifying your data so it can be saved and restored properly:  storing address + size, pointing to an object with freeze/thaw methods, a discriminated union, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the `void*` happens to point to a `std::string` then yes, it is safe.

Comment: "I want to get its value that can point to any type(int,string,float,long,char..)"

Comment: Yes, but "I want to put what contain in a string to output it" is I think saying it is a string. Frankly, it's hard to know for sure.

Comment: I thought that meant that the data was arbitary and he wants to convert it to a string...  Although I agree, it is a touch unclear.

Comment: yes the type is arbitrary and I want to convert it to a string to manipulate it after.

Answer (score 1):

No you absolutely cannot do that and expect sensible results if the void* points to say int and you cast it to std::string.  You will need to store type information somewhere, either by having a polymorphic class hierarchy to contain your data, by using boost::variant, by writing your own "discriminated union," or some other technique.

Comment: ok thanks @John, i didn't use boost::variant before I will make some research about and try it and see if fit my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not safe. How can you be sure that what you're pointing to is a string? How did you reserve this memory in the first place?

Sounds like a design issue - why do you have *data blobs* floating around whose type you don't know? Are you attempting to implement a `variant` type?

Comment: am not sure that my pointer point to a string it can be any type (int ,float, double, long, string)

Comment: It sounds like what you've got there is a variant type. You can either plug away at it yourself or it may be easier to look at `boost::variant` as others have suggested. I've done this kind of thing - creating data structures that allow complex, dynamic data storage - a few times before, but I think these days, I'd just use `boost::variant`. If you want to do it yourself then I'd suggest changing void* and instead pass a pointer to an abstract base class, from which are derived wrapper classes round your ints, doubles floats etc.

Comment: thank you for your time Component 10, I fix it by a simple enum that contain all my type values